# Datasheet view display wrong data

Tags: 2010, datasheet

I have standart view filtered by choice field. Standart view shows me 748 items. Then I switch to Datasheet View (by button on ribbon) same view shows me 175 items. Also datasheets view shows some duplicates.

If I resave view, it starts working properly, 1 day later it is broken again.

What is the reason? I've spent a day solving this problem :(
Sorry for ugly english.

Answer (score 1):

There is no fix for this problem that I am aware of and it is a bug.

Basically it is the multi value lookup column, it hates it and makes multiple rows up because of it when it is included in the view.

Comment: I have not any multi value lookup columns in my libraries but the problem still exists.

Comment: This is a odd one then, this issue occurs when an item has a one to many relationship with something else. I think more information is required. Please provide the list schema for testing.

Comment: I have used iMacros for Firefox and resaved all Views. Problem has disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3rd-party addons that bypass such Datasheet issues.
One of them is KWizCom's List Inline Editor, which also supports custom columns and works in any browser:
http://www.kwizcom.com/sharepoint-add-ons/list-in-line-editor/overview/